# question about vector space additive identity and multiplicative identity

Tags: vector-spaces

The additive identity and the multiplicative identity of a vector space seem to be very simple concepts, but there must be something basic I don't understand:   My book has an example of vector addition defined as (a1,a2) + (b1, b2) = ( a1+b1, a2b2), with vector multiplication defined as c(a1,a2) = (ca1,a2).

To me, the additive identity (zero vector) would be (0,1) but doesn't a zero vector have to be (0,0)?

And to me the additive inverse would be (-a1,0) but the book says there is no additive inverse.  This makes me think I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some confusion may arise from the name "zero vector," and even more so since we often write this as simply $0$. So for clarity let's call this vector the "additive identity." An additive identity will be the vector that when added to any other vector in the space does not change that vector. In your example, we will look for a vector, $b=(b_1,b_2)$, such that

$$(a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2)=(a_1,a_2).$$

This shows us that we are looking for some $b_1$ such that $a_1+b_1=a_1$ and some $b_2$ such that $a_2b_2=a_2$. Solving these shows that $b=(0,1)$ is such a vector, and so $(0,1)$ is the additive identity (or "zero vector").

For the next part, use this $(0,1)$ to find any additive inverse. For some point $(a_1,a_2)$, the inverse would be $(-a_1,\frac{1}{a_2})$. So, your book saying that there is not one probably means that you are in a space using only integers, and so $\frac{1}{a_2}$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

A vector space is an additively written  commutative group with some extra structure. Now the definition
$$(a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2):=(a_1+b_1, a_2b_2)$$
does not make the set ${\mathbb R}^2$ into an additive group $G$. This can be seen as follows:: Choose an $a\in{\mathbb R}$. Then
$$(0,0)+(0,a)=(0,0)$$
implies that $(0,a)$ is the neutral element in $G$. But this cannot be: The neutral element of a group is uniquely determined, while we have chosen $a\in{\mathbb R}$ arbitrarily.